# How to know if a field is numeric in Linq To SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I need to select the rows of a table where a column value is numeric, any Help?

EDIT: I have a varchar column and I need to select the ones that are numbers and the ones that are not.

EDIT 2: Integer.TryParse cannot be use because it cannot be translate to SQL.

Comment: Presumably, you would know because it's your table.  Could you clarify a bit as to why this is not the case?

Comment: I have a varchar field and I need to select the ones that are numbers and the ones that not.

Comment: It can be done, very easily and with great performance using LINQ-to-SQL and built-in SQL functions... see my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if there is a mapping for int.TryParse() in LinqToSQL, but you could probably do it in two steps by performing the query, casting to a List, then selecting out of the list with LinqToObjects.

```
int i;
var query = context.Table.ToList();
var intQuery = query.Where( t => int.TryParse( t.Column, out i ) );
```

You might want to look at [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx), too.  That would allow you to do something like:

```
var query = context.Table.Where( "IsNumeric(Column)" );
```

**EDIT** Dynamic LINQ is available in the VS2008 Code Samples, linked to from Scott Guthrie's blog, which I've linked above.

Comment: Regarding the first option: please be aware that are selecting the whole table and are only executing the where-criteria once the table is in-memory. This will not work well for larger data sets.

Answer (score 15):

Open up your DBML (LINQ-to-SQL) file in an XML editor, go down to the end of the file and paste this just before the '</Database>' node:

```
<Function Name="ISNUMERIC" IsComposable="true">
    <Parameter Name="Expression" Parameter="Expression" Type="System.String" DbType="NVarChar(4000)" />
    <Return Type="System.Boolean" DbType="BIT NOT NULL"/>
</Function>
```

Now, you can use the *already-in-SQL* function called "ISNUMERIC". Here's how:

```
var blah = myDataContext.Accounts.Where(account=>
    myDataContext.ISNUMERIC(account.ID) == true);
```

There you go :)

You may also find these functions useful to copy:

```
<Function Name="RAND" IsComposable="true">
  <Return Type="System.Double" DbType="Float NOT NULL" />
</Function>
<Function Name="NEWID" IsComposable="true">
  <Return Type="System.Guid" DbType="UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL" />
</Function>
```

Comment: I prefer the simpler method of @Josh

Comment: @billy I agree, except that's Entity Framework, and out well after the question was asked :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't quite grasp the nuance :P

Answer (score 6):

SqlFunctions.IsNumeric

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.isnumeric.aspx

For example:

```
    private int GetLastGoodNumber(string PartNum)
    {
        return (from row in Db.SerialNo
                where
                   row.PartNum == PartNum
                let nullable = System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(row.SerialNumber)
                where nullable != null
                select nullable.Value).Max();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<>.Where(x=>"0123456789".IndexOf(x.value.substring(0,1))>-1)
```

Comment: Great answer. This works with MySQL as well where SqlFunctions.IsNumeric is MSSQL specific.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Int32.TryParse ... That may work for you.

Ian

Answer (score -1):

You will not be able to do this with LINQ2SQL without loading all records on the client.

I can suggest to create view or table-valued function with aditional calculated column and then filter your results with this column. Or execute regular SQL with DataContext.ExecuteQuery.

Answer (score -2):

(Edited to suit your needs)

So, given the fact that you cannot use `Integer.TryParse`, the following is not feasible:

```
int i;
var rowsWithInts = (From r In dc.YourRows Where Integer.TryParse(r.Column, i));
var rowsWithoutInts = (From r In dc.YourRows Where !Integer.TryParse(r.Column, i));
```

Is it possible that you create a stored procedure and link it to the DataContext via the Methods Pane? In that case you can do in your SQL the following:

```
-- Rows with integers
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE ISNUMERIC(varchar_column) = 1
-- Rows without integers
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE ISNUMERIC(varchar_column) = 0
```

Does this helps?

Comment: This will load all records to the client.