# Convert string to int in linq-to-sql query: how to deal with values which cannot be converted?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I'm running this query against a database:

```
var result = (from leads in dc.T_DM_FactDemandeWebLeads
                         join  demands in dc.T_DM_DimDemandeWebs on leads.DemandeWeb_FK equals demands.DemandeWeb_PK
                         join  temps in dc.T_DM_Temps on demands.DateDemande_FK equals temps.Temps_PK
                         where leads.longitudeClient != null && (Convert.ToInt32(leads.GeolocDistanceRouteDistrib) > 1000*30) && (temps.Date > new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).Date)
                         select new Lead
                         {

                             lng = leads.longitudeClient,     

                             lat = leads.latitudeClient,

                             distance = leads.GeolocDistanceRouteDistrib

                         }).Take(1000000);
```

**Problem:** This line is buggy:

```
(Convert.ToInt32(leads.GeolocDistanceRouteDistrib) > 1000*30)
```

as leads.GeolocDistanceRouteDistrib is a VARCHAR which takes "Unknown" in some cases, leading to a [format exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx):

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Unknown' to data type int.
```

This problem is solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961675/linq-select-parsed-int-if-string-was-parseable-to-int), but the method cannot be converted to SQL.

**Question**: is there any way to rewrite the query so the conversion is done during the execution of the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the technique in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/950162/261050) to create the IsNumeric sql function in your dbml file.
And use it in your query.

Something like this:

```
join  temps in dc.T_DM_Temps on demands.DateDemande_FK equals temps.Temps_PK
where dc.ISNUMERIC(leads.GeolocDistanceRouteDistrib) // Added!
where leads.longitudeClient != null && (Convert.ToInt32(leads.GeolocDistanceRouteDistrib) > 1000*30) && (temps.Date > new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).Date)
select new Lead
```

Comment: Seems a good idea, but I still get the error: somehow the convert is called anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Add **.AsEnumerable()** to your entity, then you can use all mothods

```
var result = (from leads in dc.T_DM_FactDemandeWebLeads.AsEnumerable()
                         join  demands in dc.T_DM_DimDemandeWebs on leads.DemandeWeb_FK equals demands.DemandeWeb_PK
                         join  temps in dc.T_DM_Temps on demands.DateDemande_FK equals temps.Temps_PK
                         where leads.longitudeClient != null && (Convert.ToInt32(leads.GeolocDistanceRouteDistrib) > 1000*30) && (temps.Date > new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).Date)
                         select new Lead
                         {
                             lng = leads.longitudeClient,     
                             lat = leads.latitudeClient,
                             distance = leads.GeolocDistanceRouteDistrib
                         }).Take(1000000);
```